# How to use Sys.Services.ProfileService for non-default profile provider?

Tags: provider

I want to write javascript to save to a profile provider that is NOT the default provider specified in web.config:

```
<profile defaultProvider="SqlProfileProvider">
 <providers>
  <clear />
  <add name="SQLiteProfileProvider" applicationName="Gallery Server Pro" connectionStringName="SQLiteDbConnection" type="GalleryServerPro.Data.SQLite.SQLiteProfileProvider" />
  <add name="SqlProfileProvider" applicationName="Gallery Server Pro" connectionStringName="SqlServerDbConnection" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" />
 </providers>
 <properties>
  <add name="ShowMediaObjectMetadata" defaultValue="false" type="String" allowAnonymous="true" />
  <add name="UserAlbumId" defaultValue="0" type="Int32" allowAnonymous="false" />
  <add name="EnableUserAlbum" defaultValue="true" type="String" allowAnonymous="false" />
 </properties>
</profile>
```

I can save to the default provider with this javascript:

```
Sys.Services.ProfileService.properties["ShowMediaObjectMetadata"] = "true";
Sys.Services.ProfileService.save(null, null, null, null);
```

But how can I save to the provider named SQLiteProfileProvider?

Thanks,
Roger Martin

[Gallery Server Pro](http://www.galleryserverpro.com)